# document.styleSheets[i].disabled doesn't work in chrome

Tags: javascript, css, google-chrome, stylesheet

I have a pretty weird problem to solve; the solution should be pure JavaScript (no frameworks allowed). Here it is: "display all stylesheets that are enabled on the page".

I use chrome because of multiple issues of `innerHtml` in IE, although it has `cssText` property of a stylesheet, which suits perfectly for my purpose.

Anyway, here is my example

```
<html>
    <head>
        <style MEDIA="screen">
            h1 {color:blue; font-size:10pt; background-color:cyan}
        </style>
        <style MEDIA="screen" DISABLED="true">
            h4 {color:blue; font-size:10pt; background-color:cyan}
        </style>
        <style MEDIA="print">
            h1 {color:gray; font-size:12pt; font-weight: bold}
            h2 {font-style:italic}
        </style>
        <style DISABLED="true">
            h2 {color:green; font-size:12pt}
        </style>
        <style>
            h3 {font-style:italic}
        </style>

        <script language="Javascript">
            function displayActiveStyles() {
                var container = document.getElementById('activeStyles');                                
                var i;
                for (i=0; i<document.styleSheets.length; i++) {
                    alert(document.styleSheets[i].disabled);
                }   
            }                  
        </script>
    </head>
    <body>
        <h1>one</h1>
        <h2>two</h2>
        <h3>three</h3>
        <input type="button" value="show" onclick="displayActiveStyles()" >
        <hr />
        <div id="activeStyles"></div>
    </body>
</html>
```

The problem is, for all 5 stylesheets it alerts `false` which isn't right. If anybody has any ideas of where I am making a mistake or if it is doable in chrome at all, please let me know.

Comment: Your language and username...conflict a little ;)

Comment: chromium has a reported bug http://code.google.com/p/chromium/issues/detail?id=88310. Google is using chromium source to build their Google Chrome browser

Comment: Blender, =) good point, will "nonsense" instead of bullshit do ok?

Answer (score 0):

I understand that you want to list the href's of each stylesheet, right? In your code, you're going through each stylesheet, and alerting it's disabled property. Since they're enabled, they are alerting "false", which is correct. If you want to get the href of only the enabled ones, you could do something like:

```
var i;
for (i = 0; i < document.styleSheets.length; i++) {
    if (!document.styleSheets[i].disabled) {
        alert(document.styleSheets[i].href);
    }
}
```

Trying this here, there's one styleSheet for which its href is `null`. Not really sure why's that, I googled something quickly and it's probably because it is a `<style>` tag. You can add a check for `document.styleSheets[i].href along with the check for`disabled`.

Comment: Thanks, but no, this is not what I wanted to do. My task is to display the rules of enabled stylesheet, but it's not the point, my problem is that .disabled always returns false, although it's not so.